# Using a c# handler to serve up wav files cuts audio short (only a couple of seconds)

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler, wav

I've got a c# handler that serves up audio files I've generated using text-to-speech. When the files are written to disk they sound fine, but when I try and play them in a browser (via the handler) using a quicktime plugin it cuts them short at about 2 seconds.

Inside the handler I'm using the following code...

```
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ContentType = "audio/x-wav";

context.Response.WriteFile(fileName);
context.Response.Flush();
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try writing the file as binary data directly to the OutputStream

```
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ContentType = "audio/x-wav";
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried this and get the same result. Really strange! Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Try calling the handler from a different environment, not a browser with a quicktime plugin. maybe a download manager of some sort. see if you do get the whole file.

Comment: It works in VLC player by calling the audio file from the URL. I think the problem is that Quicktime will ask for a seeked number of bytes so maybe I need to include that in the OutputStream.Write call and get the start bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers by the way. It put me in the right direction.